# How to shift matplotlib annotations after creating them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have the following code to produce a arrow using `ax.annotate()`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

t = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.01)
s = np.cos(2*np.pi*t)
line, = ax.plot(t, s, lw=2)

at = ax.annotate('local max', xy=(2, 1), xytext=(3, 1.5),
        arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.05),
        )
ax.set_ylim(-2, 2)
```

[image]

Here, I just want to shift the arrows up/down or left/right afterwards. Is there any way to access "the coordinates" to make the shifting possible via the returned `at`.

I have tried `at.set_x()` and `at.set_y()`, but both only change one end of the arrow. **Updating the position of annotation arrows afterwards** is the key here.

Comment: It doesn’t have to be dynamic plots.. I have many situations where I have to update arrows. I only simplify the question here.

Comment: @akocz are you sure these functions exist? ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [matplotlib: how to annotate point on a scatter automatically placed arrow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074996/matplotlib-how-to-annotate-point-on-a-scatter-automatically-placed-arrow)

Comment: You might also be interested in [mplcursors](https://mplcursors.readthedocs.io/) which offers a dynamic annotation while hovering around.  Did you try `annotate(..., textcoords='offset points')` so the text keeps the same offset versus the data point when moving that point around?

Comment: @JohanC I used that method before.

Comment: @akocz, I dont think that question is related to this one. What I need is "updating"  programmatically.

Comment: Check out the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44828874/14393689

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, both `at.set_position()` and `at.set_x()` / `at.set_y()` change the text position. However, you can change the xy-coordinates directly:

```
at.xy = (new_x,new_y)
```